# getting consistent sizing for glyph backgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, textkit

Hey folks – I'm new to TextKit and trying to draw backgrounds & borders around specific attributes. I've gotten fairly close, but haven't yet found methods that don't generate very inconsistent sizing, which tends to look bad. Here's my first crack at it:

```
class MyLayout: NSLayoutManager {
    override func drawBackground(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at origin: CGPoint) {
        super.drawBackground(forGlyphRange: glyphsToShow, at: origin)

        guard let storage = textStorage else {
            return
        }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }

        var codeBlockRect: CGRect? = nil
        enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: glyphsToShow) { (rect, usedRect, container, subRange, stop) in
            var effectiveRange = NSRange()
            let attributes = storage.attributes(at: subRange.location, effectiveRange: &effectiveRange)
            storage.enumerateAttribute(.inlineCodeBlock, in: subRange) { (value, attributeRange, stop) in
                guard value != nil else {
                    return
                }
                var background = self.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: attributeRange, in: container)
                background.origin.x += origin.x
                background.origin.y += origin.y

                context.setFillColor(UIColor.lightGrey.cgColor)
                context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.mediumGrey.cgColor)
                context.stroke(background)
                context.fill(background)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That produces these results:

**Single line of text:**
[image: Single line of text]

**Multiple lines of text:**
[image: Multiple lines of text]

As you can see, there's about 3 pixels of difference between the sizes there. I imagine it's because `boundingRect`, as the documentation says:

> Returns the smallest bounding rect which completely encloses the glyphs in the given glyphRange

But I haven't found a method that gives me a number closer to what I'm looking for. My ideal scenario is that every rectangle will have the exact same height.

Let me know if any more information is needed.

#### Update

It crossed my mind that this could be related to the proprietary font we're using, so I changed everything to use UIFont.systemFont, which didn't make any difference.

Comment: I think what you need to do is override the drawing of the actual glyphs...?

Comment: I still wouldn't know what size to make them without a method that gives me that information, right?

Comment: Right but I was thinking you’d examine the actual glyphs. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here – instead of defining my `inlineCodeBlock` as a background, i defined it as a custom underline style.

Doing that let me override `drawUnderline(forGlyphRange:underlineType:baselineOffset:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:)`.

Once I had that, I was able to use `baselineOffset` to get a consistent positioning.

Comment: Seems like overkill. If that’s all you wanted to do why didn’t you just impose a consistent position for the text bottom yourself to start with?

Comment: I'm not overriding any of the glyph rendering